# What does $u_{xx}$ and $u_{tt}$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I was reading this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/220045/36790); it dealt with wave-equation; though I know the D'Alembert formula but I'm new to this notation.

What does $$u_{xx}= u_{tt}$$ and $$v_{xx}= v_{rr}$$ mean?

Sorry, if this is a dumb question but I'm new to this type of notation.

So, could anyone please help me conceive this notation?

Comment: Subscript is often used to indicate a partial derivative w.r.t. to the subscripted parameter. Presumably $u$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$, and the first equation states that
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

subscript is a derivative with respect to this variable.

$$
u_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$u$ is a two variable function $u(x,t)$,

$$u_{xx}=\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial x^2}$$.